# Javascript How to click a class (button) that is inside a class? Do it in Applescript

Tags: javascript, applescript

I'm doing automate in applescript but use Javascript in which I want to click the exact button class ("boost-button") inside a bigger class ("product-item") that contains a string I want. I want to click about 5 of them, each in every ("product-item").

It's like: Do javascript "If getElementByClassName('product-item')[0].innerHTML contains 'The String I Need to Find' then click button class 'boost-button' inside that class"

Because the element number in getElementByClassName('product-item')[0].innerHTML and the getElementByClassName('boost-button')[0].click doesn't go together, they don't click the exact same Class Button.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: What is the **URL** of the page and which buttons as seen on the page, not the _code_?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
var btn = document.querySelector(".product-item").querySelector(".boost-button")
```

or just use

```
var btn = document.querySelector(".product-item .boost-button")
```

to setup Click Event And Got All Of Your Buttons ...

```js
 var btnCollections = document.querySelectorAll(".product-item .boost-button");

    btnCollections.forEach(btn => { btn.addEventListener("click", event => EventHandler(event)); });


    function EventHandler(event) {
        console.log(event.target.textContent)
    }

        // Auto Click
    document.querySelector(".auto-click").addEventListener("click",_=>{

        var btnCollections = document.querySelectorAll(".product-item .boost-button");

        btnCollections.forEach(btn => btn.click());

    } );
```

```html
      <div class="product-item">
    <button class="boost-button"> test 1 </button>
    <button class="boost-button"> test 2 </button>
    <button class="boost-button"> test 3 </button>
</div>
<div class="product-item">
    <button class="boost-button"> test 4 </button>
    <button class="boost-button"> test 5 </button>
    <button class="boost-button"> test 6 </button>
</div>

<button class="auto-click"> Auto Click </button>
```

Other Way :

and for your click problem read click documentation and use `event.target`

Comment: Thank you sir! But there are 5  buttons I need to  click. I don't understand or know how to use event.target or where is "click documentation" can you share more information source about that. After input your code into the console, I got:  <div data-v-21e61cc7="" data-v-a988061e="" class="boost-button"><div data-v-21e61cc7="" class="boost-button-text count-cool">03:08:39</div></div>. I desperately need it Sir.

Comment: it is ok .. now i think this will be useful